# "Ask for Finder items" in automator folder action doesn't show up

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

In my folder action, I added "Ask for finder items" action (asking for destination folder for move operation) after filtered items from the folder got stored in the variable.
Whenever I add file to the folder, I can see folder action "gear" spinning in the status bar, but it stuck at "Ask for finder items" action and I don't see any dialog that asks me for destination folder.

I guess I'm missing something here?

**UPDATE**
Added screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Automator script?

Comment: @books453 added screenshot

Comment: On my system it is running.. Made an exact copy of your workflow...

Comment: @pjctech so the dialog pops up when you save music file into your downloads folder?

Comment: I think it may be showing up, but on my computer it doesn't focus so it can be buried behind some other Finder windows. I'm still searching for how to focus the prompt window but this feels like a bug to me. I'm on 10.12.5 Sierra.